# Closure law in definition of groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is closure omitted in some group definitions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63697/why-is-closure-omitted-in-some-group-definitions)

I have just started studying about groups, so pardon me if this is a lame question

while i was reading the definition. the author states that

'strictly speaking the closure law is not necessary since a binary operation on a set necessarily satisfies it'

can anyone elaborate on this statement?i am not sure i quite understand it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He just means that the definition of a binary operation includes closure, so it is not strictly necessary to include it again in the definition of a group.